# Do not reload content in the top view in a navigation on tab switch

Tags: ios, swift, uitabview

I'm on a view (lets say VC1) which is at the top of navigation stack. I click on another Tab and come back to this view, content in VC1 reloads. How do I stop reloading content in this situation as reloading doesn't make any sense since view is already loaded with content.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    loadContent()    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't stop `viewWillAppear` to be called from 2 same actions like switching tab or poping a covering vc , so you need to remove `viewWillAppear` and assign a delegate for the vc you need to reload after it's pop to call  `loadContent`

Comment: I navigate away from this view to another view and when that comes back I may want to reload that's why I've loadContent() in viewWillAppear. Is there anyway we can stop reloading in viewWillAppear ?